# run code if Database NotExists, Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i want to do a "one time work" in case database is not existing.
the work is  StaticCategoriOchArea.InsertCategoryDataInDB(); and its to insert data inside a table after the database is created just first timec.

i have tried this but i got stackoverflow.

```
public class FacilityContext : DbContext
{

    public FacilityContext()
        : base("FacilityContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UmeaKommunFacilityContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<UmeaKommunFacilityContext>());

        if (!Database.Exists())
        {
            StaticCategoriOchArea.InsertCategoryDataInDB();

        }

    }

    public DbSet<Facility> Facility { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StaticCategoris>  StaticCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StaticAreas> StaticAreas { get; set; }
}

public static class StaticCategoriOchArea
 {

 public static void InsertCategoryDataInDB()
        {

            using (var db = new UmeaKommunFacilityContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CatIds.Count; i++)
                {
                    int noOfRowInserted = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into StaticAreas (Name, AreaID ) values ('" + AreaNames[i] + "' ,'" + AreaIDs[i] + "')");
                }
            }

        }

 }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt136533%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists%601.Seed%28%600%29

Comment: A migration that happens after database creation should be fine for you, I believe.

Comment: @raderick I have to insert this table before i insert the other table

Comment: As Gert points out, that is what Seed() on your initializer is for. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx